# Object null in Android

Tags: android, string, null

I got strange results with null and strings:

```
"" + null result is null, 
null + "" result is null
"bbb" + null result is "bbbnull"
```

I expected **""**, **""** and **"bbb"**

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: show some code part too

Comment: s = null + "";
        s = "" + null;
        s = "bbb" + null; And I was wrong. Result was null in quotes

Answer (score 2):

When you attach a string as `null + ""`, it means that the compiler will interpret it `null.toString()` and `""`.

And for `null.toString()`, check out Kotlin's [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#nullable-receiver) extension.

```
fun Any?.toString(): String {
    if (this == null) return "null"
    // after the null check, 'this' is autocast to a non-null type, so the toString() below
    // resolves to the member function of the Any class
    return toString()
}
```

As you can see, when you pass in null, it will print "null". That's why you get "null" instead of not seeing it.